# Implementing Queue Using Two Stacks Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: c++, class, stack, queue

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/queue-using-two-stacks/problem
The above question requires implementing a queue using two stacks.
So what I am supposed to do is answer to 3 types of queries

1. Enqueue
2. Dequeue
3. Print Top

My code is as follows:
/*

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stack>
    using namespace std;
    
    class QueueTwoStack{
        stack<int> s1;
        stack<int> s2;
        public:
        void enqueue(int x);
        void dequeue();
        int Front();
    };
    void QueueTwoStack::enqueue(int x){ //ENQUEUE
        while(!s1.empty()){
            s2.push(s1.top());
            s1.pop();
        }
        s1.push(x);
        while(!s2.empty()){
            s1.push(s2.top());
            s2.pop();
        }
    }
    void QueueTwoStack::dequeue(){  //DEQUEUE
        if(!s1.empty())
        s1.pop();
    }
    int QueueTwoStack::Front(){ //RETURN FRONT
        return s1.top();
    }
    int main() {
        QueueTwoStack Queue;
        int q,ch,x;
        cin>>q;
        while(q--){
            cin>>ch;
            if(ch==2)
            Queue.dequeue();
            else if(ch==3)
            cout<<Queue.Front()<<endl;
            else if(ch==1){
                cin>>x;
                Queue.enqueue(x);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
*/
```

Now This Code passes 25% of test cases and giving "Time Limit Exceeded" verdict. Any Help on inefficiency
in code or approach?. Also I want to ask that does using classes slow down the code?

Comment: For each new element, you are emptying stacks twice. Pushing all from s1 to s2 and then back to s1. You can use one stack to push new ones (s1) and one stack to pop (s2). If s2 is empty, then push all the elements of s1 into s2

Comment: Please provide a [mre] what is your code supposed to do? I can't read your hacker rank link

Comment: 1) Get yourself a compiler.  2) Copy the test case that fails into a file.  3) Rewrite your code so you are reading from that file.  4) Debug your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are maintaining a fully sorted queue in stack `s1`, enqueuing elements by shoving all of `s1` into `s2`, adding the next element, and then shoving all of `s2` back into `s1`. This is not very optimal.

Let us instead call the stacks `in` and `out`. In the beginning both are empty:

```
in:  <top>
out: <top>
```

Enqueuing elements just adds them to `in`. Adding 1,2,3:

```
Add 1:
in:  1 <top>
out: <top>

Add 2:
in:  1 2 <top>
out: <top>

Add 3:
in:  1 2 3 <top>
out: <top>
```

Dequeuing elements just pull them from `out` - with the caveat that if `out` is empty, we transfer all of `in` to `out` first:

```
Dequeue:
in:  1 2 3 <top>
out: <top>            <- empty! Transfer

in:  <top>
out: 3 2 1 <top>

Out no longer empty, pop 1:

in:  <top>
out: 3 2 <top>
```

Doing it this way ensures that every element is only touched exactly three times: First when added to `in`, second when transferred from `in` to `out`, third when popped from `out`.